# Debian all sudo commands fail with 'user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.' error

Tags: linux, debian, files, sudo, password

I tried out Linux for the first time. When I installed Bullseye Debian a few hours ago I created a root account and user account. Both of them have a password. However whenever I try to use `sudo` to update my system it is always denied. Also what does `This incident will be reported` mean? Did I do someting wrong? Will my device be banned from using Debian?

```
luke@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get update

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for luke: 
luke is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
luke@localhost:~$
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/838/

Answer (score 4):

No, this is just a warning on your local machine.  The fact that you attempted to gain root access and were not an authorized user is just recorded locally in an audit log.  It is not sent outside your machine.  You have not done anything wrong and you will not be banned from using Debian.

To add luke to the sudoers file, login as root and add "luke" to the group allowed to sudo.  For example:

```
usermod -a -G sudo luke
```

Comment: `bash: usermod: command not found`